# Netbeans: Why is there always a commit when I merge two branches?

Tags: git, netbeans

Each time I merge my master branch with a development one, a merge commit is added, even if there is no conflict between the 2 branches.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZVKK.png)

Could someone explain it to me, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you probably have --no-ff set as default. However, to know why, you could check the log of that merge commit: git show <commit_id>

Comment: Based on the wording of your question you may want to read up on how merges work. [Here's one of many references](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging). Note whether a merge commit is created is not about conflicts, instead it's about whether or not a "fast-forward" merge is possible and if it is, then whether or not the option to do that is overridden.